# appendTo() inside $.each in jquery seems to cause flicker

Tags: jquery, appendto

appendTo() causes flicker when it is inside $.each....

```
$.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                $('<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>').appendTo('#ResultsDiv');
            });
```

Right now i am appending every new div to `#ResultsDiv` inside`$.each` is it good/bad to do so... If it is bad
What can be done to make my divs `appendTo()` after the loop so that i it wont flicker....

**EDIT:**(based on answer)

```
var divs = '';
            $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
            });
            $("#ResultsDiv").append(divs);
```

But that too doesn't stop the flicker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending to the DOM is a very expensive task to perform especially in a loop. You should try to add all your results to a string and then do one append after the each loop:

```
var dataToAppend = '';
$.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
            dataToAppend += '<div class="resultsdiv" style="display:none"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
        });
$('#ResultsDiv').append(dataToAppend);
$('#ResultsDiv').removeAttr('style');
```

The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.

Also try adding `display:none` to the `resultsdiv` and then remove that style after you perform the append to see if that helps with the flickering.

Comment: You could add display:none to your resultsdiv class and then after the append operation remove that style.  It is probably flickering since you are adding elements to the DOM and they need to be rendered, so maybe hiding them as they get added and then showing them at once will help.

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
var divs = '',
    $result = $("#ResultsDiv"),
    $parent = $result.parent();

    $result.empty().detach();

        $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
            divs += '<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>';
        });
        $result.append(divs);
        $parent.append($result);
```