# Variable from each loop: undefined

Tags: jquery, json, undefined

I'm getting data through JSON

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/'
            + '?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos'
            + '&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' 
            + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey 
            + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', 
    function (data) {
        var fullPhotoURL, flickrLink;
        var images = [];
        var basePhotoURL;
        var fullPhotoURL;

        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (i, flickrPhoto) {
            var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm 
                 + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' 
                 + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";

            var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm 
                + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' 
                + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";

            images.push($("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL));
        });

        $.each(images, function (index, img) {
            img.appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"));

        });

    });
```

I want to append two a's (with href basePhotoURL & fullPhotoURL) to each .item div.

```
$(".item")
    .append("<a href='" + basePhotoURL + "'.jpg' class='zoom' />");
$(".item")
    .append("<a href='" + fullPhotoURL + "' class='flickr' target='_blank' />");
```

Problem is, when i put those in the second each function, those two a's get appended for every .item that is present in #photographs (divception :-)) (so, 300 items x 2 a's PER .item). When i put those two a's outside the last each function, i get an undefined error. by the way, don't mind the fullPhotoURL and basePhotoURL variables' values; they are not correct.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need two loops there?

Comment: This was proposed from another stackoverflow thread actually.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the motivation for the second loop too. Could you provide a link to that thread?

Comment: The second loop is so that you only do one paint/append to the DOM, instead of every loop around adding it again and again.

Comment: 2 loops don't help at all, you have the same amount of insertions. Only solution would be a surrounding div, then it would be just 1 append.

Comment: second loop isn't necessary.. loop can be removed and you can wrap with jQuery `$(images).appendTo('#photographs').wrap("<div class='item'/>");`

Comment: Even by splitting, it's still painting twice per image.

Comment: mpcDESIGNS, that to me that only makes sense if you do it in this setting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2544891/1355555. That is, in your loop, create a single string containing all the data, then append that string to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback; it's a mindopener. I'm still quite new to this stuff; i'm learning alot! Thanks!

Comment: Umm nvm.. some reason that only works in jQuery 1.8.3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making things harder than they have to be.  Here's my proposed changes.

```
.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {

    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";  

        var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";          

        var $img = $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL);
        var $wrap = $("<div class='item'></div>");
        $wrap.append($img);
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + basePhotoURL + "'.jpg' class='zoom' />");
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + fullPhotoURL + "' class='flickr' target='_blank' />");

        $wrap.appendTo('#photographs')

    });

});
```

So now we're generating the img, then its wrapper, then appending the img to the wrapper, then appending the anchors to the wrapper, then appending the wrapper to the photographs div.  And we're doing it all within one loop, all at once.  No need for a second loop, and thus no need for an image array.

Comment: Excellent. As i've typed in the other answer; thanks for the help; i'm still new at this and i'm learning fast! I can't test right now; but i'm guessing this is correct and will help me in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just append them directly to the div tag?

```
    var div = $("<div class='item'></div>");
    div.append(....);
    div.append(....);
```

Also, you cant access the variables from the first loop in your second loop. If you really need 2 loops for some reason you can pass them along in the array.

```
    images.push({base: basePhotoURL, full: fullPhotoURL});
```

and create the img in the second loop (or pass it along with the rest).

If you are concerned about performance, do:

```
    var plist = $("<div></div>");
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (i, flickrPhoto) {
        var row = $("<div class='item'></div>");

         //add stuff

        plist.append(row);
    });
    plist.appendTo("#photographs");
```

Comment: Thanks (see other answers for info)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of Eli's answer, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2544891/1355555) post. Here you'll append the data to the DOM only once.

```
.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {

    var dataToAppend = ''
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";  

        var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";          

        var $img = $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL);
        var $wrap = $("<div class='item'></div>");
        $wrap.append($img);
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + basePhotoURL + "'.jpg' class='zoom' />");
        $wrap.append("<a href='" + fullPhotoURL + "' class='flickr' target='_blank' />");
        dataToAppend += $wrap;
    });
    $'#photographs').append(dataToAppend);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It all looks logical when it's there, but i when i have to figure it out myself.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the format your looking for using this as well, basically the same thing.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function (data) {
    var fullPhotoURL, flickrLink;
    var images = [];
    var basePhotoURL;
    var fullPhotoURL;

    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (i, flickrPhoto) {
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";
        var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_b.jpg";

        $('<img/>', { 'src': basePhotoURL }).appendTo("#photographs").wrap('<div/>', { 'class': 'item' }).append('<a href="' + basePhotoURL + '.jpg" class="zoom" /> <a href="' + fullPhotoURL + '" class="flickr" target="_blank" />');
    });
});
```